# Azure Powershell script completes, but the Azure portal says the operation is still ongoing

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm writing a solution that will move an azure database out of an elastic pool, run a long and DTU intensive operation, and then move the database back into the pool. I'm trying to use azure powershell to automate the scaling part (using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-move-database-between-pools-powershell?toc=%2fpowershell%2fmodule%2ftoc.json) as a guide). However, I noticed that when the powershell command completes, the azure portal still shows that the database has an "1 ongoing operation".

Is there some way to tell when the operation is *really* complete?
Or perhaps is waiting for the powershell script to complete good enough? I did notice the pool membership was already updated in the portal.

Comment: Any update this issue? If my reply is helpful, you could mark it as answer for others to refer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to tell when the operation is really complete? Or perhaps is waiting for the powershell script to complete good enough? I did notice the pool membership was already updated in the portal.

To check the operation if completes or not, you could navigate to the portal -> **your resource group** -> **Activity log**, check the logs.

You can also check it with powershell, etc. For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit).